# Concatenating to stdout, then splitting on stdin - is this possible?

Tags: shell, concatenation

I have am looking to solve the problem of writing a series of very large streams concatenated to stdout, and then reading those streams from stdin again, splitting the streams into their original parts. The limitation I face is that at no time can I create any temporary files on disk.

I tried to use the unxz --singe-stream option, but this isn't having the effect I'm expecting.

To demonstrate what I am trying to achieve, I have two scripts:

```
user@localhost:~# cat test-source.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "one" | xz
echo "two" | xz
echo "three" | xz
```

The above first script is then piped into the second script that is intended to reverse the effect:

```
user@localhost:~# cat test-sink.sh 
#!/bin/bash

unxz --single-stream
unxz --single-stream
unxz --single-stream
```

The above script is expected to output the following:

```
one
two
three
```

Instead I see the following:

```
user@localhost:~# ./test-source.sh | ./test-sink.sh 
one
unxz: (stdin): File format not recognized
unxz: (stdin): File format not recognized
```

The xz above was just one option I tried, I am open to other suggestions. gzip wants to uncompress the whole stream at once, I need to preserve the boundaries between the streams.

I understand that tar is no good, as it cannot accept a stream to tar from stdin.

Is there any other tool out there that can be used to script this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will solve your problem or not (since it would require installing some software, which given the nature of this question is maybe not an option), but you inspired to hack together something that does exactly what you were describing:

- https://github.com/larsks/muxdemux

You can iteratively produce an output stream from several chunks, as in:

```
echo "one" | xz | mux
echo "two" | xz | mux
echo "three" | xz | mux
```

And then pass that to a `demux` command on the other side to extract the individual components.  E.g, a trivial example:

```
$ (
  echo "one" | xz | mux
  echo "two" | xz | mux
  echo "three" | xz | mux
  ) | demux -v
INFO:demux:processing stream 0 to stream-0.out
INFO:demux:processing stream 1 to stream-1.out
INFO:demux:processing stream 2 to stream-2.out
```

This takes the input streams and produces three files in your current directory.

It does other other things, too, like optionally adding a sha256 hash
to each stream for data integrity verification.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative tool I came up with tarmux, which provides a multiplexer / demultiplexer written in C and based on the tar file format provided by libarchive.

- https://github.com/minfrin/tarmux

The test scripts now look like this:

```
Little-Net:trunk minfrin$ cat ./test-source.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "one" | tarmux
echo "two" | tarmux
echo "three" | tarmux
```

And this:

```
Little-Net:trunk minfrin$ cat ./test-sink.sh 
#!/bin/bash

tardemux
tardemux
tardemux
```

The output of tardemux can be piped into other commands, and at no point does a file touch a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Given your source script script, if I run:

```
sh test-source.sh | unxz
```

I get as output:

```
one
two
three
```

That seems to be the behavior you're asking for.  Your attempt at running `unxz --single-stream` several times doesn't work because the first `unxz` process consumes all of the input, even though it only extracts the first stream.

Comment: It's not the behaviour I am looking for no, thus the error "unxz: (stdin): File format not recognized".

What I need to happen at the end is that the three separate streams being muxed together on the source side must be demuxed into three separate streams on the sink side, where they can be processed by a command.

Right now what is happening is that the first invocation of unxz processes the first stream correctly, then swallows the second and third streams, resulting the data being passed to the wrong place.

Comment: This seems to implement exactly what you described in terms of output, and I explained the cause of that error message in this answer.  Can you elaborated (in your question, ideally) how the behavior you want differs from the behavior presented here?

Comment: The error messages I am getting are well understood, the reason I included them was to demonstrate the undesirable behaviour I am seeing.

As stated in the original question, I am looking to solve the problem of writing a series of very large streams concatenated to stdout, and then reading those streams from stdin again, splitting the streams into their original parts.